# How to add a custom column in Tasks section on Pulse in Magnolia

Tags: java, magnolia, pulse

Good morning, i am a fairly new person at Magnolia and i have the need to improve a web by showing more data at the Task section of Pulse in Magnolia, to be able to do that i need to create a couple of columns but after trying to find some information at Magnolia documentation y have only been able to find this "[Add custom column to Inbox](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Add+custom+column+to+Inbox)", but unfortunately is outdated and the Inbox class that makes reference is not used anymore in the newers versions of Magnolia.

Could somebody help me and explain to me how to create these columns at the Tasks section of Pulse in Magnolia?, or point me in the rigth direction?.

Im using the Magnolia version 5.3 with a Maven setup, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish here, is that when you enter the pulse and you are presented whit the inbox of the Tasks and Messages i can add a custom column in the task inbox, sorry if its difficult to understand what im trying to pull here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add additional column to pulse tasks, you should be dealing with java code unfortunately.

Have a look at  `info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.shellapp.pulse.task.TasksListViewImpl#constructTable` and there you will see the following:

```
    table.addGeneratedColumn(NEW_PROPERTY_ID, new PulseNewItemColumnGenerator());
    table.setColumnWidth(NEW_PROPERTY_ID, 100);
    table.addGeneratedColumn(TASK_PROPERTY_ID, new TaskSubjectColumnGenerator());
    table.setColumnWidth(TASK_PROPERTY_ID, 220);
    table.addGeneratedColumn(STATUS_PROPERTY_ID, new TaskStatusColumnGenerator());
    table.setColumnWidth(STATUS_PROPERTY_ID, 80);
    table.addGeneratedColumn(SENT_TO_PROPERTY_ID, new SentToColumnGenerator());
    table.setColumnWidth(SENT_TO_PROPERTY_ID, 100);
    table.addGeneratedColumn(LAST_CHANGE_PROPERTY_ID, new DateColumnFormatter(null));
    table.setColumnWidth(LAST_CHANGE_PROPERTY_ID, 140);
```

Just adjust it to your needs.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks Ducaz, but im trying to add them without having to change the code of the magnolia core product, like creating mi own proyect with the classes of the magnolia core modified and them making the reference at the magnolia configuration. I think its posible through the TaskListPresenter in the magnolia modules/ui-admincentral/config/pulse/presenters/task But im having some issuess whit the import of the classes.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do it programmatically or you can change the code as well and have it configured via JCR. Nevertheless either way you have to touch the code.

Comment: At the end we updated our version to 5.14 and from that point fowards i can call the class responsible for the creation of the Task Inbox with the Magnolia Configuration, so i recreated the class responsible for the visualization of the Task Inbox added the new columns and added a few other clasess to fill the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I yet follow what you're trying to achieve.  Do you want to add a column to a view, as in one of these images?
[image]
[image]

If not, could you please make some kind of mockup of what you hope to achieve?

Is there some reason you are using such an old (> 2 years) version of Magnolia? If not, perhaps I could also help you migrate to the latest and greatest (5.5.7)?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: We are currently movin to Magnolia 5.4.14 but for us its imposible to move further at this point. I cant add images because where i work we had a huge number of internet pages that have some sort of restriction so we are unable to enter them. What i am trying to accomplish here, is that when you enter the pulse and you are presented whit the inbox of the Tasks and Messages i can add a custom column in the task inbox, sorry if its difficult to understand what im trying to pull here.

Comment: Now that Ducaz035 has answered, I would refer you to his answer :)